# R matching more than 2 conditions and return the response value

Tags: r, match

Hi I have two data set where the first one is a set of index:

```
ind1<-rep(c("E","W"), times=20)
ind2<-sample(100:150, 40)
y<-c(1:40)
index<-data.frame(cbind(ind1, ind2, y))
```

The second data set is the one needs to be indexed.

```
x1<-sample(c("E","W","N"), 40, replace=TRUE)
x2<-sample(100:150, 40)
x3<-rep(0, times=40)
data<-data.frame(cbind(x1,x2,x3))
```

I would like indicate in `x3` where the `x1` and `x2` in `data` to be matched with `ind1` and `ind2` in `index` respectively and return the corresponding `y`.

```
index1<-split(index, index$ind1)
data1<-split(data, data$x1)
data1$E$x3<-match(data1$E$x2, index1$E$ind2)
data1$W$x3<-match(data1$W$x2, index1$W$ind2)
```

It kinda matched the way I wanted but did not return `y` correctly. Which part I did wrong?
Thanks.

Also, is there a faster/smarter way of doing it? Because I might have more conditions to match with. Originally I tried if else statement but didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
merge(data, index, by.x=c("ind1", "ind2"), by.y=c("x1", "x2"), all.x=TRUE, all.y=FALSE)
```

will give you the `x` and `y` values for each matching combination of `ind1` and `ind2`, and `x1` and `x2`. All combinations of `x1` and `x2` will be kept (even if that combination of `ind1` and `ind2` doesn't occur in `index`, but combinations of `ind1` and `ind2` that don't occur in `data` will be dropped. As written, the solution will keep `x3` and `y` values, but if you'd like to drop the `y` values you can use `merge(data[ ,-3], ...` as per @Ferdinand.kraft 's suggestion.

Comment: Maybe `merge(data[,-3], index, by.y=c("ind1", "ind2"), by.x=c("x1", "x2"), all=TRUE)`?

Comment: Wow, thanks. Maybe I did not state my question clearly enough. I need to keep `data` as it is with the matching `y` according to `index`.

Comment: I think I got it. with @Drew Steen 's solution to get only the matching pairs. Then use @Ferdinand.kraft 's solotion to merge the matching pairs with `data`. Thank you both. :D

Comment: Edited to reflect @Ferdinand.kraft's point - although my understanding now is that OP wants to keep all combinations of `x1` and `x2` in `data`, but is OK dropping combinations of `ind1` and `ind2` that appear in `index` but not in `data`.

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to approach this, and it really depends on the characteristics of your data.  Here is the most direct matching approach:

**Pasting**: The 'paste' function allows you to create a string from multiple pieces of data.  If you are a matching between data sets using columns that have identical matches, you can simply paste the columns together and compare directly using a 'match' statement, like so:

```
new_data <- data

new_data$x3 <- ifelse(
    is.na(match(paste(data$x1, data$x2), paste(index$ind1, index$ind2))),
    0,
    index$y)
```

The match statement here compares exact matches between x1+x2 and ind1+ind2 pairs and returns an integer indicating which index pair location corresponds to each data row.  If no match is found, NA is returned.  By checking for NA in an 'ifelse' statement, we then write zeros for the NA values and return the corresponding y value for any matches.

Comment: Appreciate! That saved me a lot of time in subsetting!

Comment: @Dinre it seems that your solution is buggy. It does not generate accurate matching values. The correct way would be to use the index$y[match(......)] followed by a is.na statement to replace NA with zeroes.

Answer (score 4):

you can use also `left_join()` from `dplyr` package:

```
require(dplyr)
left_join(data, index, by = c("x1" = "ind1", "x2" = "ind2"))
```

read more [here](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/relational-data.html)

Answer (score 1):

This question is related to [match two data.frames based on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26596305/10488504).

You can use [interaction](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/interaction) or [paste](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/paste) as already suggested by [Dinre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18320673/10488504), to *match on multiple columns*.

```
#Write the row number of index in x3 which matches
data$x3 <- match(interaction(data[c("x1", "x2")]), interaction(index[c("ind1","ind2")]))

#In case you want to return 0 instead of NA for nomatch
data$x3 <- match(interaction(data[c("x1", "x2")]), interaction(index[c("ind1","ind2")]), nomatch=0)

#Instead of >interaction< you could also use paste as already suggested by Dinre
data$x3 <- match(paste(data$x1, data$x2), paste(index$ind1, index$ind2))
```