# R: Case-insensitive matching of a combination of first and last names (i.e. two columns) across two dataframes

Tags: regex, r, match

In R, I should like to extract the people who completed both versions of a test I designed and subsequently administered in two phases (I asked participants for their first and last names).

The problem is that 1. people aren't consistent in using capitals; and 2. some people might share a first name or last name with other people.  Thus, 1. I need a case-insensitive search; and 2. I should like to extract a new data frame that lists the first and last names of the first version, and the first and last names of the second version, in order to verify the match (also because someone might use "Tom" in one instance and "Thomas" in another):

```
df1 <- data.frame(firstName = c("John", "Josef", "Tom", "Huckleberry", "Johann"),
                  lastName = c("Doe", "K", "Sawyer", "Finn", "Bach"))

df2 <- data.frame(firstName = c("John", "josef", "Thomas", "Huck", "Pap", "Johann Sebastian", "Johann"),
                  lastName = c("Doe", "K", "Sawyer", "Finn", "Finn", "Bach", "Pachelbel"))
```

The above names should all provide a match for me to verify:

```
repeatDF <- data.frame(firstName.1 = c("John", "Josef", "Tom", "Huckleberry", "Huckleberry", "Johann", "Johann"),
                       lastName.1 = c("Doe", "K", "Sawyer", "Finn", "Finn", "Bach", "Bach"),
                       firstName.2 = c("John", "josef", "Thomas", "Huck", "Pap", "Johann Sebastian", "Johann"),
                       lastName.2 = c("Doe", "K", "Sawyer", "Finn", "Finn", "Bach", "Pachelbel"))
```

Of which I then (probably manually?) approve all but "Johann Pachelbel" and "Pap Finn", as they might match name-wise, but aren't the same person as the one they're matched to.

So far I have tried `merge` (see also [match two data.frames based on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596305/match-two-data-frames-based-on-multiple-columns)) and `%in%`, but both methods are case-sensitive and miss out on some matches.  I somehow can't get an `apply` function to work using `grep` (must admit: not very fluent with either of those functions), but also don't know how to take into account both first and last name using `grep`?  Am I looking in the right direction, or should I use an altogether different function?

Any help would be much appreciated!

PS.  There seem to be many, many similar questions, but either for different programmes or not requiring both of my considerations – apologies though if there is indeed already an answer to my question!

Comment: No mention of Dietrich Buxtehude deserves a downvote, but I'll spare you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work based on OP's comments and new dataset. I changed `df2` slightly so the names are not in the same order in both data frames.

```
df1 <- data.frame(firstName = c("John", "Josef", "Tom", "Huckleberry", "Johann"),
                 lastName = c("Doe", "K", "Sawyer", "Finn", "Bach"))

df2 <- data.frame(firstName = c("John", "josef", "Huck", "Pap", "Johann Sebastian", "Johann", "Thomas"),
                  lastName = c("Doe", "K", "Finn", "Finn", "Bach", "Pachelbel", "Sawyer"))
get.match <- function(A,B) {
  A <- as.list(tolower(A)); B <- as.list(tolower(B))
  match.last  <- grepl(A$lastName,B$lastName)|grepl(B$lastName,A$lastName)
  match.first <- grepl(A$firstName,B$firstName)|grepl(B$firstName,A$firstName)
  match.first | match.last
} 

indx    <- apply(df2,1,function(row) apply(df1,1,get.match,row))
indx
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]
# [1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

m.1     <- df1[rep(1:nrow(df1),apply(indx,1,sum)),]
result  <- cbind(m.1,do.call(rbind,apply(indx,1,function(i)df2[i,])))
result
#       firstName lastName        firstName  lastName
# 1          John      Doe             John       Doe
# 2         Josef        K            josef         K
# 3           Tom   Sawyer           Thomas    Sawyer
# 4   Huckleberry     Finn             Huck      Finn
# 4.1 Huckleberry     Finn              Pap      Finn
# 5        Johann     Bach Johann Sebastian      Bach
# 5.1      Johann     Bach           Johann Pachelbel
```

So this uses an algorithm implemented in `get.match(...)` which compares a row of `df1` to a row of `df2` and returns `TRUE` if the first name in either row is present in the first name of the other row *or* the last name in either row is present in the last name of the other row. The line:

```
indx    <- apply(df2,1,function(row) apply(df1,1,get.match,row))
```

then creates an `indx` matrix where the rows represent rows in `df1` and the columns represent *rows* of `df2` and the element is `TRUE` if the corresponding rows of `df1` and `df2` match. This allows for the possibility of more than one match in either `df1` or `df2`. Finally we convert this `indx` matrix to the `result` you want using:

```
m.1     <- df1[rep(1:nrow(df1),apply(indx,1,sum)),]
result  <- cbind(m.1,do.call(rbind,apply(indx,1,function(i)df2[i,])))
```

This code extracts all the rows of `df1` which have matches in `df2`, and then binds that to the corresponding rows from `df2`.

Comment: If it looks for a match of _both_ first _and_ last name, then wouldn't it also exclude for example "Tom Sawyer" (in df1) when df2 has "Thomas Sawyer"?  (I updated my question to include this potentiality, as I just noticed it wasn't yet in there)

Comment: Yes. Change the `&` to `|` in `get.matches(...)`.

Comment: This seems to work really well, up to the point of `result`: I get a `data.frame` with the matches of `df1` and `df2`, but the matches in `df2` aren't in the same row as the names of `df1` (i.e. `# John   Doe      Huck   Finn` in one row, and `# Josef   K      John   Doe` in another row)?

Comment: I found the problem:  in my (simplified) example, the names in both data.frames occupy the same row, whereas in my actual data they do not since there are many other names (non-repeat participants) interspersed.

Comment: I see what you mean. Posting a new version now.