# Matching values from two column pairs in different data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, match, pairwise

I have two data frames which are edge lists containing columns "source" and "target" as their first two columns and the second data frame includes a third column with edge attributes. The two data frames are not of the same length and I want (1) to retrieve the edges from one data frame that are not in the other and (2) to get the values from the second data frame for matching edges.

Example:

```
> A <- data.frame(source=c("v1", "v1", "v2", "v2"), target=c("v2", "v4", "v3", "v4"))
> B <- data.frame(source=c("V1", "V2", "v1", "V4", "V4", "V5"), target=c("V2", "V5", "V3", "V3", "V2", "V4"), variable=c(3,4,0,2,1,0))
> A
  source target
1     v1     v2
2     v1     v4
3     v2     v3
4     v2     v4
> B
  source target variable
1     V1     V2        3
2     V2     V5        4
3     v1     V3        0
4     V4     V3        2
5     V4     V2        1
6     V5     V4        0
```

desirable outcome (1):

```
  source target
1     V2     V5
2     V1     V3
3     V4     V3
4     V5     V4
```

desirable outcome (2):

```
  source target variable
1     V1     V2        3
2     V2     V4        1
```

How can this be achieved with R?

Comment: See: [match two data.frames based on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26596305/10488504)

Comment: Why is V4->V2 not in outcome 1? Direction doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first you will get with an `anti_join`, though you will need to anti-join on both combinations of source and target since direction appears not to matter in your example. Note I've had to use `toupper` because the capitalization in your example was erratic and the example suggested case should be ignored.

```
library(dplyr)

anti_join(anti_join(B, A %>% mutate_all(toupper), 
                    by = c("source", "target")),
          A %>% mutate_all(toupper), 
          by = c(target = "source", source = "target")) %>%
  select(-variable)
#>   source target
#> 1     V2     V5
#> 2     v1     V3
#> 3     V4     V3
#> 4     V5     V4
```

The second result you can get from binding two `inner_join`s:

```
bind_rows(inner_join(B, A %>% mutate_all(toupper), 
                     by = c("source", "target")), 
          inner_join(B, A %>% mutate_all(toupper), 
                     by = c(source = "target", target = "source")))
#>   source target variable
#> 1     V1     V2        3
#> 2     V4     V2        1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`:

```
# Load data.table and convert to data.frames to data.tables
library(data.table)
setDT(A)
setDT(B)

# If direction doesn't matter sort "source/target"
# Also need to standardise the data format, toupper()
cols <- c("source", "target")
foo <- function(x) paste(toupper(sort(unlist(x))), collapse="-")
A[, oedge := foo(.SD), .SDcols = cols, by = seq_len(nrow(A))]
B[, oedge := foo(.SD), .SDcols = cols, by = seq_len(nrow(B))]

# Do anti-join and inner join
B[!A, .SD, on="oedge", .SDcols=cols]
#    source target
# 1:     V2     V5
# 2:     v1     V3
# 3:     V4     V3
# 4:     V5     V4
B[A, .SD, on="oedge", .SDcols=c(cols, "variable"), nomatch = NULL]
#    source target variable
# 1:     V1     V2        3
# 2:     V4     V2        1
```