# Merging data frames without duplicating data when several matches are possible

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, duplicates, merging-data

I need merge two data frames, without having duplicate rows/duplicated data if there is more than one match. Basically, if the matching between my dataframes is ambiguous, I would like the ambiguous rows to NOT be matched, and each row to remain separate instead.
I've been using the *merge* function, but it states that **If there is more than one match, all possible matches contribute one row each**, and I got to the same result using *join*/*inner_join* functions. Is there a way to fix this ?

Example:

df1

| ID | Question 1 | Question 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 | 2 |
| B1 | 3 | 4 |
| C1 | 5 | 6 |
| C1 | 7 | 8 |

df2

| ID | Question 3 | Question 4 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | a | b |
| B1 | c | d |
| C1 | e | f |
| C1 | g | h |

What I get using merge by ID

| ID | Question 1 | Question 2 | Question 3 | Question 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 | 2 | a | b |
| B1 | 3 | 4 | c | d |
| C1 | 5 | 6 | e | f |
| C1 | 7 | 8 | g | h |
| C1 | 5 | 6 | g | h |
| C1 | 7 | 8 | e | f |

What I want

| ID | Question 1 | Question 2 | Question 3 | Question 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 | 2 | a | b |
| B1 | 3 | 4 | c | d |
| C1 | 5 | 6 | NA | NA |
| C1 | 7 | 8 | NA | NA |
| C1 | NA | NA | e | f |
| C1 | NA | NA | g | h |

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to identify the `duplicated` id's, exclude them when using `merge` and `rbind` them afterwards.

```r
X <- unique(c(df1$ID[duplicated(df1$ID)], df2$ID[duplicated(df2$ID)]))
plyr::rbind.fill(merge(df1[!df1$ID %in% X,], df2[!df2$ID %in% X,]),
                 df1[df1$ID %in% X,],
                 df2[df2$ID %in% X,])
#  ID Question1 Question2 Question3 Question4
#1 A1         1         2         a         b
#2 B1         3         4         c         d
#3 C1         5         6      <NA>      <NA>
#4 C1         7         8      <NA>      <NA>
#5 C1        NA        NA         e         f
#6 C1        NA        NA         g         h
```

---

Data

```r
df2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="ID     Question3   Question4
A1  a   b
B1  c   d
C1  e   f
C1  g   h")

df1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
ID  Question1   Question2
A1  1   2
B1  3   4
C1  5   6
C1  7   8")
```

Comment: Wow, this is such a quick and efficient way, thank you so much ! Is it possible to use *unique* for two colums at the same time ? (my post was oversimplified, in real life, I have IDs + dates for the matching, and my problem is duplicates on ID+date combinations)

Comment: Yes both `unique` and `duplicated` work also for multiple columns, but `%in%` will not. There you can use `interaction`, `paste` or `asplit`. See: [match two data.frames based on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596305).

Answer (score 1):

I always seek to avoid many to many merges by creating a case variable for each duplicate id and then merge by ID case.

Like below:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("A1", "B1", "C1", "C1"), Q1 = c(1, 3, 4, 7), Q2 = c(2, 4, 6, 8))
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c("A1", "B1", "C1", "C1"), Q3 = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), Q4 = c("b", "d", "f", "h"))
library(dplyr)

df3 <- full_join(df1, df2, by = "ID")

df3

df11 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(case = row_number())

df22 <- df2 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(case = row_number())

tmp <- df22 %>% summarise(count = n())

df22 <- merge(df22, tmp, by = c("ID"))

df22 <- df22 %>% mutate (case = ifelse(count==2,case+2,case))
df22

df33 <- full_join(df11, df22, by = c("ID", "case"))
df33
```

which returns:
[image]