# R matching more than 2 conditions in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Does anyone know how to deal with more than 2 conditions using `%in%` in `dplyr` like as in [this exapmle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18319985/r-matching-more-than-2-conditions-and-return-the-response-value)?

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not link, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained. Also: Please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inner_join` (and the other joins) support arbitrarily many columns to join by.

For instance:

```
inner_join(a, b, by = c('x', 'y', 'z'))
```

Or, if the column names differ:

```
inner_join(a, b, by = c(x1 = 'x2', y1 = 'y2', z1 = 'z2'))
```